# Is it possible to add leaderboards with libgdx for IOS?

Tags: ios, libgdx

The title says it all.  But I have already created my libgdx app and have just launched it on the itunes store.  I really want to add leaderboards to it, but I'm not entirely sure how to make it with game center, and googling around didn't really give me much information.  I was looking at swarm but that doesn't really help much in terms of ios I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the already suggested solution may work I would suggest Google Play Services via this:
[Tutorial to include GPGS in iOs on LibGdx](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11424)

It is possible to style it as you want and according to various users it works like a charm.